# How to get Google gadgets URL parameters

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-gadget

A [Google gadget](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/) is an iframe embedded in a gadget container like [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com/). 
Example: https://sites.google.com/site/michaelmccolin/test

However, since Google gadgets and Google Sites are on two different domains you cannot get the gadget parent URL using `window.parent.location`. The good news is the parent URL is included as a parameter value in the gadget (iframe) URL. Example:
https://slr19h92al8so047kuchhg5aog1sb42l-a-sites-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/ifr?url=http://hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/116132513635841516857/sample.xml&container=enterprise&view=default&lang=en&country=ALL&sanitize=0&v=3bad4b3f87c8b199&libs=core&mid=167&parent=https://sites.google.com/site/michaelmccolin/test#st=e%3DAIHE3cDvCGmbZDEAvjS%252BWTpqst9FseOLNB%252BMd8IoyLxY3kypcxAriuGzs%252FtCova0JAhrFqKK2kKB3qFgru2PBUTYWMIIcmPaw4iAl7DIaUqyPKO56DpM9mcbQqh1bIa23t89yrL7maxL%26c%3Denterprise&rpctoken=9057528913578437337

The question is how I can get the `parent` parameter value from the gadget URL.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the query string as follows:

```
var queryString = location.search.substr( 1 );
```

From there on, it's easier to split it at the delimiters and create an object out of it:

```
var queryObject = {};

queryString.split( '&' ).forEach( function objectFromPair( pairString ){
    var pairArray = pairString.split( '=' );

    queryObject[ pairArray[ 0 ] ] = pairArray[ 1 ];
} );
```

Next, retrieve the `parent` key:

```
var parentUrl = queryObject.parent;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `location.search` gave me an idea: is it OK to simply use `location.search.split('parent=')[1]`?

Comment: @RainLover you easily could, but only because `parent` happens to be the last parameter in the query string (although, if it wasn't, you could still get it in one line by executing `location.search.split('parent=')[1].split('?')[0]`. The method above is more verbose, but more reusable — BTW, I made a couple of corrections in the answer above if you decide to go for that solution.